# Find diff between MySQL tables, only returning rows where a specific column has changed

Tags: mysql, union, diff

I need to diff two MysQL tables, and report on changes to a subset of the results.

Let's say I have these two tables:

Table A:

```
id      name        supplier        value
-----------------------------------------
1       Alice       X               100
2       Bob         Y               200
3       Clare       Z               300
4       Desmond     X               400
```

Table B:

```
id      name        supplier        value
-----------------------------------------
1       Alice       X               150
2       Bob         X               200
3       Clare       Z               350
4       Desmond     X               400
5       Emily       X               500
```

I'm interested in changes to any row involving supplier X. Given the above, I want to return:

- ID 1, because the supplier is X and the value has changed;
- ID 2, because the supplier has changed from Y to X;
- ID 5, because the supplier is X and there's no corresponding row in table A.

I'm not interested in ID 3 because, while the value has changed, the change doesn't involve supplier X. I'm also not interested
in ID 4 because there is no change at all.

---

I can use `UNION ALL` to compute the diff:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT a.id, a.name, a.supplier, a.value, 'a' as tbl
   FROM a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.id, b.name, b.supplier, b.value, 'b' as tbl
   FROM b
)  t
GROUP BY id, name, supplier, value
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY id
```

This returns all rows where the data has changed:

```
id      name        supplier        value       tbl
---------------------------------------------------
1       Alice       X               100         a
1       Alice       X               150         b
2       Bob         Y               200         a
2       Bob         X               200         b
3       Clare       Z               300         a
3       Clare       Z               350         b
5       Emily       X               500         b
```

However, it is also including ID 3 which I'm not interested in, because neither the row from table A or B has supplier X.

So finally, my question is - **how to return results where one of the diffed rows is supplier X**? I could of course filter the results in code, but it would be great to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it using two `LEFT JOINS` with a `UNION`:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `supplier` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `value` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `supplier` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `value` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;

INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'Alice', 'X', 100);
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (2, 'Bob', 'Y', 200);
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (3, 'Clare', 'Z', 300);
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (4, 'Desmond', 'X', 400);

INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'Alice', 'X', 150);
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (2, 'Bob', 'X', 200);
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (3, 'Clare', 'Z', 350);
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (4, 'Desmond', 'X', 400);
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`, `supplier`, `value`) VALUES (5, 'Emily', 'X', 500);

SELECT a.name AS name, a.supplier AS a_supplier, a.value AS a_value, b.supplier AS b_supplier, b.value AS b_value FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
WHERE (a.supplier ='X' OR b.supplier = 'X') AND (a.value <> b.value OR a.supplier <> b.supplier OR b.name IS NULL)
UNION 
SELECT b.name AS name, a.supplier AS a_supplier, a.value AS a_value, b.supplier AS b_supplier, b.value AS b_value  FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.name = a.name
WHERE (a.supplier ='X' OR b.supplier = 'X') AND (a.value <> b.value OR a.supplier <> b.supplier OR a.name IS NULL)
```

First, you join table `A` to table `B`, second you do a reverse join.

I'm not sure whether you can join the tables by their ids, so I used names as a join column for this example.

Every join includes a `WHERE` clause which filters the rows using your cirteria: *"changes to any row involving supplier X"*.

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46f213/1

Comment: This works perfectly when joining with IDs, thank you. My example was rather simplified, whereas the real dataset has about 20 columns and 250k rows, but this is running once daily so doesn't really matter if it takes a while to run.

Comment: @Graham glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can likely add some where clauses to your original query to check for Supplier X but I think I'd take a slightly different approach and use a join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.supplier, a.value, b.name, b.supplier, b.value
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id AND (a.name != b.name OR a.value != b.value OR a.supplier != b.supplier))
WHERE a.supplier = 'X' OR b.supplier = 'X'
GROUP BY a.id;
```

This gets rows that have changed but only those related to X. Note that this assumes there is always exactly one matching id in each table.

Comment: in this case your 'OR' clause will increase the query cost. That's not the optimised solution

Comment: Hmm, yes this works when the IDs exist in both tables, but unfortunately it won't catch instances where table A includes rows not existing in B, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Extending lldar's answer, you could also get the difference by hashing your columns and then looking for changes.

```
md5(concat(A.`Name`,A.`Supplier`, A.`Value`)) <> md5(concat(b.`Name`,b.`Supplier`,b.`Value`))
```

this is helpful if you have many columns. Ideally on a longer term, you may edit the tables and add the hash as "computed/calculated" column.

then it would be simply `A.hash <> b.hash`

Comment: Yes I had considered this, thinking that storing a computed hash would speed up the query significantly. In practise though, the time taken to compute the hash values is about 30 seconds (I have to use `UPDATE tbl SET hash = md5(...)` rather than computing at insert time), which vastly outweights the suprisingly marginal benefit of using it in the query (~2s vs ~3s without).

Comment: @Graham you don't update a computed/generated column!

Answer (score 0):

requirement could be achieved by using LEFT JOIN only

```
SELECT b.NAME AS NAME, 
       a.supplier AS a_supplier, 
       a.value AS a_value, 
       b.supplier AS b_supplier, 
       b.value AS b_value
FROM   b 
       LEFT JOIN a 
              ON ( a.id = b.id ) 
WHERE  ( b.supplier = 'X' 
          OR a.supplier = 'X' ) 
       AND ( a.supplier != b.supplier 
              OR a.value != b.value 
              OR a.id IS NULL ) 
ORDER  BY b.id;
```